# how to compare date and time in php/ mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i need to compare date and time in php/mysql basically i have an application and a server the application needs to connect to the server to check new entries into the database. the server receives the datetime as a string from the application which is done here

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String time = dateformat.format(cal.getTime());
```

the server receives the data here

```
f (isset($_GET["time"]) || isset($_GET["user_id"])) {
$time = $_GET['time'];
$u_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$timestr=date('y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($time));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(created_at)from room");
$Max_time = mysql_result($result, $row);
$dbMax_time = date('y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($Max_time));
```

and the comparison needs to be done here

```
if ($dbMax_time> $timestr) {
    $NewRooms = mysql_query("SELECT * From room WHERE created_at> CAST($timestr AS TIME)");
}
```

how do i go about this am confused on how to compare please help me to FIX it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just comparing two timestamps would suffice:

```
$t1 = strtotime($time);
$t2 = strtotime($Max_Time);

if($t1 > $t2) { .. }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you create two DateTime objects and compare these?

Like:

```
$A = new DateTime(); 
$A->setTimestamp(strtotime($time));

$B = new DateTime(); 
$B->setTimestamp(strtotime($Max_Time)); 

if ($A > $B) echo "You use if statements to compare"
```